# Queryhistory for a range of changeset in TFS for specific info

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to use C# and TFS to get a release log out of the comments of changesets in TFS.

I have this code:

```
        const string tfsURL = "http://dev.ger.test.com:8080/tfs";

        var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsURL));

        VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
        var tp = vcs.GetTeamProject(@"MyCollection");
        var path = tp.ServerItem;
        path += @"/Project/Subproject";

        var q = vcs.QueryHistory(path, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, null, null, 1, true, true, false, false);

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            Logger(item.ToString(), false);
        }
```

which works, but it only returns the latest changeset and all information inside this changeset.

So my questions are:

How do I specify a range of changeset in queryhistory like VersionSpec.1000 to VersionSpec.Latest?

How can I manipulate item in my foreach loop to display specifig information like item.Comment ?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I edited the QueryHistory to be

```
var q = vcs.QueryHistory(path, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, new ChangesetVersionSpec(23618), VersionSpec.Latest, 1, true, true, false, false);
```

which changed nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
var changes = vcs.QueryHistory(
    path, 
    VersionSpec.Latest, 
    0, 
    RecursionType.Full, 
    null, 
    VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("C100", null), // starting from changeset 100
    VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("C200", null), // ending with changeset 200
    int.MaxValue, 
    true, 
    false);

 foreach(Changeset change in changes)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", change.ChangesetId, change.Comment);
 }
```

It will get you changesets 100 to 200 and list their IDs and comments